# TestNG - test executed but tests run = 0

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver, testng

I'm trying to run TestNG with Selenium in Eclipse.

When the Class file is Run As a TestNG Test, I'm getting the Tests Run = 0.

What could the issue be?

I have the testNg plugin & jar files configured.

**testng.xml file:**

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="WikiTestSuite" verbose="3" parallel="methods">
    <test name="WikiTestCase">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.selenium.WebDriverTest" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

**Classes:**

*WebDriverTest class*:

```
package com.selenium;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@Test
public class WebDriverTest extends BrowserInstance{

    private void WebDrive() {

        // navigate to specified browser
        wDriver.get("http://www.wikipedia.com");

        // assert wikipedia is opened
        Assert.assertEquals(wDriver.getTitle(), "http://www.wikipedia.com");
        System.out.println("Page title is correct. PASS!");
    }

}
```

*BrowserInstance class*:

```
package com.selenium;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;

public class BrowserInstance {
    // initialize webdriver object reference
    WebDriver wDriver;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void launchBrowser() {

        wDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
        System.out.println("In launchBrowser method");
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void closeBrowser() {
        wDriver.close();
        wDriver.quit();
        System.out.println("In closeBrowser method");
    }
}
```

**Note:**

*When I run the testing.xml file as a TestNG Suite, the results are*:

```
[TestRunner] Running the tests in 'WikiTestCase' with parallel mode:methods
[RunInfo] Adding method selector: org.testng.internal.XmlMethodSelector@7426dbec priority: 10
[TestClass] Creating TestClass for [ClassImpl class=com.selenium.WebDriverTest]
[TestNG] Running:
  /Users/developer/Documents/workspace/SeleniumTest1/lib/testng.xml

[SuiteRunner] Created 1 TestRunners
[TestRunner] Running test WikiTestCase on 1  classes,  included groups:[] excluded groups:[]
===== Test class
com.selenium.WebDriverTest
  @BeforeMethod BrowserInstance.launchBrowser()[pri:0, instance:com.selenium.WebDriverTest@4979935d]
  @AfterMethod BrowserInstance.closeBrowser()[pri:0, instance:com.selenium.WebDriverTest@4979935d]
======
===== Invoked methods
=====
Creating /Users/developer/Documents/workspace/SeleniumTest1/test-output/WikiTestSuite/WikiTestCase.html
Creating /Users/developer/Documents/workspace/SeleniumTest1/test-output/WikiTestSuite/WikiTestCase.xml

===============================================
    WikiTestCase
    Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
WikiTestSuite
Total tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

*When I run the .java file as a TestNG Test, the results are*:

```
[TestNG] Running:
  /private/var/folders/q6/xqd3z8fx69z05pbclbx_bj740000gp/T/testng-eclipse--953413131/testng-customsuite.xml


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Suite
Total tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

In both cases, the result is "Tests Run = 0".

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
I found the solution: I used a 'private' method in my .java file.

I was able to rectify the bug but I'm now wondering why TestNG does not run a private method.

Any input is welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: When you say “I used a 'private' method” do you mean that was the solution? Or that caused the problem? If you have a different question you should update your question.

Comment: private means it is only visible inside of the class.  TestNG is external from the class and will only run public methods.

Answer (score 0):

You should add "@Test" on test (WebDrive) method. also I am not sure if private Test run. So cross check with public

Answer (score 0):

I checked, even the default access modifier does not work, you have to specify as public for testng to run your method.

Answer (score -3):

You need to add @Test annotation to "private void WebDrive()" method or change the access modifier to public i.e from private void WebDrive(). to public void WebDrive()